# How to prevent EmberJS list from displaying deleted records?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am having problems getting my EmberJS/Ember-Data project to NOT display deleted records.

I have a route: users/route.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        console.debug('UserRoute.model');
        return this.store.findAll('user');
    }
});
```

the template: users/template.hbs

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover" style="table-layout:fixed">
        {{#each model as |user|}}
            <tr {{action "editUser" user}} class={{user.status}}>
                <td>{{user.userid}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The user route: user/route.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        deleteUser: function(user) {
            var record = this.modelFor('user');
            record.destroyRecord().then(() => {
                this.transitionTo('users');
            });
        },
    }
});
```

user template generates the deleteUser action.

Using Ember Inspector on the user model data with id 59

[image: Using Ember Inspector on the user model data with id 59]

After calling destroyRecord￼:

the network transaction headers

[image: the network transaction headers]

and response payload from backend

￼[image: and response payload from backend]

Now the user record flags in the store

[image: Now the user record flags in the store]

But the item continues to be displayed in the users route, allowing one to view and subsequently try to delete again only to receive the error:

[image: error]

￼What am I doing wrong!

Thanks,
Barry

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the success response status from the backend as `204` with empty body.

If you are using expressJS, the response will be only `res.sendStatus(204);`

Follow rest-api best practices
http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this gonna work, but if I was you I would try:

```
var currentUser = this.modelFor('user');

store.find('user', currentUser.id).then(function (user) {
 user.deleteRecord();
  user.get('isDeleted'); // => true
  user.save(); // => DELETE to /users/:id
});

// OR
store.find('user', currentUser.id).then(function (user) {
  user.destroyRecord(); // => DELETE to /users/:id
});
```

Similar code can be found from official site:
[guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/creating-and-deleting-records/](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/creating-and-deleting-records/)